# Centralizar uma imagem dentro de um TextView

Tags: android

Como faço para centralizar uma imagem dentro de um TextView ? Eu utilizei o atributo:

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/email"
```

Porém a imagem fica descentralizada:

[image: Imagem Descentralizada dentro de um TextView]

Neste caso eu consigo trabalhar com esta imagem dentro do TextView ou neste meu caso é melhor utilizar um ImagemView depois um TextView ?

Agradeço

Comment: Recomendo que poste o código XML para podermos analizar. Recomendo também que utilize os elementos com o conteúdo mais lógicos, no caso o TextView com Texto e o ImageView com Imagens, porque assim não terá que fazer nenhuma gambiarra e não terá problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Se essa não for a solução por favor responda o post com o código do XML.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/some_drawable"
    android:text="some text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Tente usar as propriedades abaixo para alinhar o hint e a imagem ao centro, eu fiz um teste rápido aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
```

**android:layout_gravity**  Gravity specifies how a component should be placed in its group of cells.

**gravity** Gravity for the view associated with these LayoutParams.